# Do LTS releases get the newest program versions?

Tags: package-management, updates, software-center, update-manager, versions

New versions of programs can sometimes be found in the official packages of newer Ubuntu releases.

For example, the DAE-software Asunder gets installed in version 2.8-3 in 16.04, while the most current, fully-updated version in 15.04 is still 2.7-2.

Is this because 15.10 will lose support in a few weeks or do LTS releases also not always receive the newest versions of featured programs? If not, is it possible to update the newer packages somehow?

Comment: Possibly related, if only to explain why the latest software isn't in a given release at any given time:  ["Why don't the Ubuntu Repositories have the latest versions of Software?"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Answer (score 1):

No package will typically be updated beyond the major version shipped with the initial release of the distribution. Minor updates may be released provided changes are not significant, and security fixes from newer versions may be back-ported to maintain compatibility.

You will find that some packages independently offer newer major versions from their own repos, but that's at their discretion and those packages wouldn't be supported by Canonical.